# Gtk widget minimum and maximum width/height with resizable to true

Tags: gtk, gtkmm3

I am new to gtk and using gtkmm-3.0, what i am trying hard is to set the minimum width and height for the gtk widget. I used set_size_request method but the widget is still crossing its min/max size when i resize the parent container.

my code looks like

```
foo::foo()
{
    set_default_size(400,400); // set default size for window
    add(grid_layout);

    menu_bar.append(file);
    menu_bar.append(edit);
    menu_bar.append(project);
    menu_bar.append(settings);
    menu_bar.append(help);


    right_panel_notebook.insert_page(right_btn, "Page1", Gtk::POS_RIGHT);
    right_panel_notebook.insert_page(notebook_btn, "Page2", Gtk::POS_RIGHT);
    right_panel_notebook.set_size_request(400,300); // setting size for a Notebook widget       


    design_paned.set_vexpand(true);
    design_paned.add1(btn);
    design_paned.add2(right_panel_notebook);


    grid_layout.set_row_homogeneous(false);
    grid_layout.set_column_homogeneous(true);
    grid_layout.attach_next_to(menu_bar, Gtk::POS_RIGHT, 1,1);        
    grid_layout.attach_next_to(design_paned, Gtk::POS_BOTTOM, 1,1);        

    show_all();
}
```

So, is there any way to restrict the widget's min/max size with its resizable to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but looking to your code, the set_size_request is being called on the GtkNotebook which is inside a GtkPaned, so:

[GtkPaned](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Paned.html) childs have two properties, **`resize`** and **`shrink`**:

> Each child has two options that can be set, resize and shrink . If
>   resize is true, then when the GtkPaned is resized, that child will
>   expand or shrink along with the paned widget. If shrink is true, then
>   that child can be made smaller than its requisition by the user.
>   Setting shrink to FALSE allows the application to set a minimum size.
>   If resize is false for both children, then this is treated as if
>   resize is true for both children

If `shrink`is set to `TRUE` then the notebook can be smaller that the 400x300 size you've requested.

To set these properties, use the GtkPanned [`pack1`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Paned.html#a20c1df3426b948d56150ad1600bcd7b3) and [`pack2`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Paned.html#ab888df4f410adaca6bd832a4ae51c20a) methods instead of the `add1` and `add2`.